# how to close a parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, firefox, mozilla

I have a application form when I submit the form it is redirecting to window which have options "print" and close.

```
Please click <a  onclick="self.close();" href="#">here</a> to close this window.
```

If I click on close,the tab itself closing in chrome and IE but it not working in Mozilla.

When I use this code,

```
Please click <a  onclick="CloseWindow();" href="#">here</a> to close this window.

<script type="text/javascript">

    function CloseWindow() {
         open(location, '_parent').close()
    }
</script>
```

it is redirecting to apply online page.

How I will close the tab itself.

`self.close();` is working for IE and Chrome but in Mozilla it shows the error:

> Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Or can we make ' dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows, true;' using c# or javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using that way? Just use:

```
function CloseWindow() {
  window.parent.close();
}
```

Or, you can use:

```
function CloseWindow() {
  window.close();
}
```

Comment: @ praveen: when i use this it gives the error in mozilla, 'Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.'

Comment: Okay @josna Give me a moment.

Comment: @josna: due to usability issue, scripts cannot close windows that were not opened by script. Imagine an annoying situation when your popup is closed by a script.

Comment: it didn't  work in Mozilla.Yet now i didn't get the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using script in HTML wrap it with  tag like:

```
Please click <a  onclick="CloseWindow();" href="#">here</a> to close this window.
<script type="text/javascript">
   function CloseWindow() {
      window.parent.close();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: @ Manwal: when I use this it gives the error in Mozilla, 'Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.'

Comment: End of script use `</script>` for closing script tag.

Comment: Can you add your complete code in question with `<script>` tag?

Comment: Where is end of script tag?

Comment: Yes end of script tag is there.