# How to close the parent window from a child window in Successfactors lms?

Tags: javascript

I have uploaded a course in Successfactors LMS. At the time of launching the course, it will open in a new window. LMS is the parent window and the course is the child window. Now I want to close both the windows LMS and Course window from the course window when exit the course.

window.opener, window.top.opener are used in the child window to close the parent window. But these codes are closed the child window instead of the parent window.

```
function closeParent(){
var wnd = window;
if((wnd.opener != null) && (typeof(wnd.opener) != "undefined")){
wnd.opener.close();
}
}
```

I am not sure Successfactors LMS is blocking the parent window reference. Please let me know, how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
function closeParent() {
  window.parent.close();
}
```

[Here is description link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182928/how-to-close-a-parent-window)

Comment: This won't work in Firefox if the parent window is not opened via script. Correct me if I'm wrong.